# ASP.NET fileupload doesn't work in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website project in local and connection with database which database in server. I can add photo and country which I work in local but I can't add which I load project to server

public void resim_ekle()
   {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();

```
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // şifreli isim
            string fileName2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            if (File.Exists(fileName + fileExtension))
                fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            if (File.Exists(fileName2 + fileExtension))
                fileName2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            if (FileUpload1.FileContent == null)
                return;
            if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length == 0)
                return;

            System.Drawing.Bitmap originalBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileUpload1.FileContent);

            int origWidth = 800;
            int origHeight = 600;

            int origWidth2 = 120;
            int origHeight2 = 90;

            double sgnRatio = Convert.ToDouble(origWidth) / Convert.ToDouble(origHeight);
            double sgnRatio2 = Convert.ToDouble(origWidth2) / Convert.ToDouble(origHeight2);

            System.Drawing.Bitmap newBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(originalBMP, origWidth, origHeight);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap newBMP2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(originalBMP, origWidth2, origHeight2);

            System.Drawing.Graphics oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            System.Drawing.Graphics oGraphics2 = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBMP2);

            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
            oGraphics2.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

            oGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Low;
            oGraphics2.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Low;

            oGraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            oGraphics2.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;

            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, origWidth, origHeight);
            oGraphics2.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, origWidth2, origHeight2);

            newBMP.Save(Server.MapPath("~/resimler/olkeler/" + fileName.ToString() + fileExtension));
            newBMP2.Save(Server.MapPath("~/resimler/olkeler/kucuk/" + fileName2.ToString() + fileExtension));


            olkeler ulke = new olkeler();



            ulke.resim_buyuk = ("~/resimler/olkeler/" + fileName.ToString() + fileExtension).ToString();
            ulke.resim_kucuk = ("~/resimler/olkeler/kucuk/" + fileName2.ToString() + fileExtension).ToString();
            ulke.olke_adi = txtulke_adi.Text;
            vt.insert_ulke(ulke);

            label_Uyari.Text = "Resim Başarıyla Yüklendi...";
        }
        catch { label_Uyari.Text = "Resim Yükleme İşlemi Esnasında Bir Hata Oluştu. Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz..."; }
    }
    else { label_Uyari.Text = "Resim Seçilmemiş..."; }

}
```

This code run in my loclhost but doesn't work in server. `FileUpload1` has no file in server

Comment: without any form of Exception how can anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: fileupload work localhost but dosent work in server .if i work in local i can add any fhoto but when i load proje to sever i cant add new photo because FileUpload1 came emty which prje run in server but no give error

Comment: FileUpload1 came is empty which proje run in server but when i run loacl FileUpload1 came not empty .as resul of progam not enter this function and dont add

Comment: have you looked at the error code, if there is any <customErrors mode="Off" />

Comment: before <customErrors mode="Off" /> but now making  <customErrors mode="On" /> but yet dont wiev error code

Comment: not error my control  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    { do something } but FileUpload1 is empty on run server and dont enter program flow this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's wrong with your

```
newBMP.Save(Server.MapPath("~/resimler/olkeler/" + fileName.ToString() + fileExtension));
```

I think you shall loose the ~

I write:

```
profilPic.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"images/people/") +
                                 profilPic.FileName);
```

from here:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="profilPic" runat="server" />
```

Comment: newBMP.Save(Server.MapPath("~/resimler/olkeler/" + fileName.ToString() + fileExtension));
                newBMP2.Save(Server.MapPath("~/resimler/olkeler/kucuk/" + fileName2.ToString() + fileExtension));
                olkeler ulke = new olkeler();
                ulke.resim_buyuk = ("~/resimler/olkeler/" + fileName.ToString() + fileExtension).ToString();
                ulke.resim_kucuk = ("~/resimler/olkeler/kucuk/" + fileName2.ToString() + fileExtension).ToString(); can you rewrite form me .Yes i tired profilPic is not empty .but i cant which you say